# How to remove space and special character before the values in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some numerical values in 1 column which are separated by commas, However, the problem is I also have sometimes 2 commas and space in one row. which are creating 3 columns and i need only 2 columns. The dummy data is below:

```
   Col A
12.55, 1345
 ,13, 1346
, 14, 1347
15.2, 1348
,15.8, 1349
```

what i want is like that

```
       Col A          Col B    col C
    12.55, 1345       12.55    1345
     ,13, 1346          13     1346
    , 14, 1347          14     1347   
    15.2, 1348         15.2    1348
    ,15.8, 1349        15.8    1349
```

I shall be really thankful for your suggestions and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[['Col B', 'Col C']] = df['Col A'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(filter(lambda x: x != '',str(x).split(','))))
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove commas:

```
df['Col A'] = df['Col A'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Then split:

```
df[['Col B', 'Col C']] = df['Col A'].str.split(' ', 1, expand = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness regular expression for this task following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['12.55, 1345',' ,13, 1346',', 14, 1347','15.2, 1348',',15.8, 1349']})
df[['B','C']] = df.A.str.extract(r'([^,]*),\s(\d+)$')
print(df)
```

gives output

```
             A      B     C
0  12.55, 1345  12.55  1345
1    ,13, 1346     13  1346
2   , 14, 1347     14  1347
3   15.2, 1348   15.2  1348
4  ,15.8, 1349   15.8  1349
```

*(tested in pandas 2.0.1)*